# Trust custom CA in electron-builder's autoUpdater, without importing to system

Tags: certificate, electron, auto-update, electron-builder, certificate-authority

How can we programmatically make the autoUpdate of electron-builder trust a specific custom CA certificate when fetching updates using the `GenericHTTPServer` provider? The solution should not involve importing the certificate to the system and should be portable to all platforms: linux, macOS and windows.

I'm neither a node.js nor an electron expert. There seem to be a number of different API's around for accessing resources via HTTP, and I don't know which of those are used by the auto-updater. The following things I have tried:

- [`electron.app.importCertifictate`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appimportcertificateoptions-callback-linux): Does not exist on macOS (and according to the docs, neither on windows). I haven't tried it on linux.
- Handling the electron [`certificate-error`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-certificate-error): Does not seem to be triggered when auto-updater checks for updates.
- Using the [`NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_extra_ca_certs_file) environment variable did not have any effect. Also, this [comment on a electron-builder GitHub issue](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/922#issuecomment-268868252) suggests that electron-builder uses the electron http services, not those of node.
- The documentation of the [`electron.net`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/net) API claims that it tries to follow closely the Node API, but does not mention anything related to certificates.

Comment: By following source-code, I was able to confirm that electron-updater (part of electron-builder) uses `electron.net.request`. So the question remains: How to configure certification validation for that API?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: [electron-userland/electron-builder - issue #3453](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/3453#issuecomment-436521777)

Comment: @Pang: Indeed - I had opened that issue more or less simultaneously when I asked this question. Since it is closed now: If you write the essentials of the solution there (i.e. `AppUpdater.netSession.setCertificateVerifyProc`) into a nice answer, I'll accept it.